# getJson fails to call Struts2 action

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var $ = jQuery;
    $(function(){
        $("#introForm").submit(function(){

            $.getJSON('ajax/test.action', formInput,function(data){    
                alert(data.greeting);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  id="introForm">
    <label >Enter Your Name</label>

    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml action

```
 <package  extends="json-default" name="jsonStruts2" namespace="/ajax" >
    <action name="test" class="com.vrde.daems.action.TestAction" method="sayHello">
        <result type="json"></result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Java Class(TestAction.java)

```
public class TestAction {
    private String greeting;

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    public String sayHello()
    {
        greeting = "Hello Ajax";
        return "success";
    }
}
```

`sayHello()` method is not getting called when i click on the submit button..but the contents in json format are displayed on the browser when i directly type the url `localhost:8000/ajax/test`
Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery;
    $(function(){
        $("#introForm").submit(function(){
            $.getJSON('./test.action', formInput,function(data){
                alert(data.greeting);
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This will work if you are refering to the action in the same controller...

Comment: thats the namespace which you have removed...it is required

Comment: You have the methods under the namespace right so if you are already in the namespace, you don't need to have it in the url it will be automatically be constant and whatever your action from the namespace will take the place after slash...

Comment: i tried removing the namespace... still its not working.. and by the way the html page is in application root folder

Comment: I m not getting any errors..its redirecting to same page..actually it should display message in alert box

Comment: @user1831612: If you are using FireFox then, probably $.getJSON() will not work. You will have to use $.ajax()

Comment: Debug in firebug or something similar to see if the request is completed from the namespace...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $ = jQuery;
$(function(){

    $("#introForm").submit(function(){


        $.getJSON("<s:url action='test' namespace='ajax' includeParams='none' />", formInput,function(data){

            alert(data.greeting);
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `formInput` is undefined in your script. You need to remove it from `getJSON`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $ = jQuery;
   $(function(){
     $("#introForm").submit(function(){
        $.getJSON('ajax/test.action', function(data){
            alert(data.greeting);
        });
        return false;
     });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your input to type button like this `<input id="btn_send" type="buttom">` and your script to

```
$("#btn_send").click(function(){

   $.getJSON('ajax/test.action', $('#formInput').serialize(), function(data){    
        alert(data.greeting);
   });
});
```